# Pass data object to an Activity from another activity (Fragment -> its Activity-> new Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, fragment, parcelable

I have created listFragment class called "EventFragment" and i need to pass data object on its click event to pass drawerActivity class (fragment class) and then i need to pass that object to another activity called EventDisplayActivity class. I could manage get data object to the drawerActivity class but i cant send that to the EventDisplayActivity class.

```
//DrawerActivity code
@Override
public void OnEventItemClick(ZEvent zEventObject) {

    Log.i("URI uri", ""+zEventObject.getEventName());

    zEventItem = (ZEvent)zEventObject;
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("EVENT_ITEM", zEventItem);

    Intent i = new Intent(DrawerActivity.this, EventDisplayActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("DUMMY","dummytext");
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(i);   

}

// EventDisplayActivity

@Override
protected void onInit(ModelBase... data) {

    System.out.println("onInit() Called in Event Display Activity");

    SharedPreferences sessionkey = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("session_detail", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);        
    session_token = sessionkey.getString("session", "");
    logged_user_type = sessionkey.getString("user_type", ""); 
    logged_user_id = sessionkey.getString("user_id", "");

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    ZEvent zEventbundle = extras.getParcelable("EVENT_ITEM"); 


    mProposalId = zEventbundle.getProposalID();
    String mDummy = getIntent().getStringExtra("DUMMY");      

    Log.i("id>>>",""+mProposalId +"Dummy"+mDummy);

    params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("token", session_token);
    params.put("proposal_id", mProposalId);

mApiClient.getView(eventViewURL, params, eventResponse);

}    

//LOgCat

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{gg.zing/gg.zin.zing.events.activities.EventDisplayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at gg.zin.zing.events.activities.EventDisplayActivity.onInit(EventDisplayActivity.java:431)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your ZEvent implements Parcelable...
If it does, then put in in the intent using putExtra (instead of creating new Bundle and using putExtras), and extract the same way using getParcelableExtra.

> ```
> // Put     
> final Intent intent = new Intent(context, <class>);
> intent.putExtra("MY_EVENT", obj); // <-- Should be parcelable
> ```

```
// Get.
ZEvent obj = intent.getParcelableExtra("MY_EVENT");
```

Comment: yes. I havent implemented ZEvent (Model class) as Parcelable. The way you suggest to sent the Data object also correct. Thank you for help

Answer (score -1):

You can also define a static attribute in a class which is used to hold the data in static fields.

```
public class AppData{
    public static String user = "Ben";
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public void setUser(String user){
    AppData.user = user;
}
```

Comment: you must send params with bundle or events (interfaces), if u use static data u will get memory out of bounds